# How can i get bot username? telegram bot C#

Tags: telegram-bot

I try to get bot username with the **bot.GetMeAsync();** but I couldn't do that.

```
var me = bot.GetMeAsync();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Result to block until the task had completed.

```
var me = Bot.GetMeAsync().Result;
Console.WriteLine(me.Username);
```